# How to send Mysql changes from local server to online live server

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-migration

I have created a web app locally in WAMP with PHP and a MySQL database. I am about to launch a demo online on a Linode server.

My question is once I have got it live on LINODE and I want to add a new Mysql table locally on WAMP how do i push the MYSQL changes to the live version online.  I am not sure what this is called and how to do it.  if anyone can share ideas/videos that would be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a MySQL Replica, in which the replicated database will only be read from.

That or you can create some type of CI/CD pipeline which will run the same queries on your local as the remote, but that's a bit more complex.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).